# How Java 8 is able to infer lambdas argument type

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, vert.x

I'm currently playing with Vert.x in Java and noticed that the examples in the documentation use lambdas extensively as callback parameters. For example:

```
NetServer server = vertx.createNetServer();
server.listen(1234, "localhost", res -> {
  if (res.succeeded()) {
    System.out.println("Server is now listening!");
  } else {
    System.out.println("Failed to bind!");
  }
});
```

Looking into the documentation of `listen` functions shows the following:

```
NetServer listen(int port,
                 String host,
                 Handler<AsyncResult<NetServer>> listenHandler)
```

My question is how does the JVM have a chance to deduce generic data types such as `Handler<AsyncResult<NetServer>>` out of such non-informative objects such as `res`? This seems fine for languages like JavaScript that do duck-typing, but for languages like Java that do strong typing, it's not as obvious for me. If we use an anonymous class instead of a lambda, all data types would be on the plate.

--EDIT--
As already explained by @Zircon, probably better example from Vert.x documentation would be following declaration:

```
<T> void executeBlocking(Handler<Future<T>> blockingCodeHandler,
                         Handler<AsyncResult<T>> resultHandler)
```

with example of usage from docs:

```
vertx.executeBlocking(future -> {
  // Call some blocking API that takes a significant amount of time to return
  String result = someAPI.blockingMethod("hello");
  future.complete(result);
}, res -> {
  System.out.println("The result is: " + res.result());
});
```

Where type of  is not available, thus only methods available on `Future` and `AsyncResults` can be used.

Comment: Well method signature states exactly of what type is 3rd argument.

Comment: Isn't `res` declared before ?

Comment: @Tomas are you asking how the compiler works? type inference?

Comment: read up on type inference - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference

Comment: In a nutshell, the compiler (_not_ the JVM) is saying: "this method takes a Handler, and that's a valid interface for a lambda, and this lambda has the same number of inputs as Handler's only method; so I can assume the lambda is for the Handler." The details are more complicated, of course, but that's the gist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler infers the type in the same exact way you do.

`Netserver.listen` takes a `Handler<AsyncResult<NetServer>>` as its third parameter.

`Handler` is a vertx FunctionalInterface with one method `handle(E event)`. In this case, `E` is `AsyncResult<NetServer>`.

Inserting a lambda here makes it take the place of `Handler.handle`. Therefore, the single argument `res` must be of type `AsyncResult<NetServer>`. This is why it can then call `AsyncResult.succeeded` without issue.

Simply:

It is impossible for the third argument of `listen` to be anything but `Handler<AsyncResult<NetServer>>`, so the lambda must be offering an argument of type `<AsyncResult<NetServer>>`.

**Edit:**

About using nested generics in a lambda, consider this class:

```
public class myClass<T> {
    public void doSomething(int port, String host, Handler<AsyncResult<T>> handler) {
        //Stuff happens
    }
}
```

(In this case, we don't care about the stuff happening.)

However, consider how we need to *call* this method. We need to have an instance of MyClass, which also means we need to declare the generic type before we call `doSomething`:

```
MyClass<String> myObj = new MyClass<String>();
result = myObj.doSomething(port, host, res -> {
  if (res.succeeded()) {
    System.out.println("I did a thing!");
  } else {
    System.out.println("I did not do a thing!");
  }
});
```

In this case, the compiler can *still* infer `res` as an `AsyncResult<String>`, because `T` is `String` in this case. If I unwrapped the `AsyncResult`, I could then call `String` methods like `toUpperCase` and whatnot.

If you end up referencing a `MyClass<?>` and attempt to similarly make use of the lambda, `res` will be inferred as an `AsyncResult<?>`. (You can unwrap the `?` type, but because it's type can't be known at compile-time you are forced to treat it is as an `Object`.)

If we don't declare a generic type during declaration, we will get a warning about it and as a consequence of raw typing this code won't work (Thanks Holger):

```
MyClass myObj = new MyClass(); //Generic type warning
result = myObj.doSomething(port, host, res -> {
  if (res.succeeded()) { //Error
    System.out.println("I did a thing!");
  } else {
    System.out.println("I did not do a thing!");
  }
});
```

Because we've declared `myObj` as a raw type of `MyClass`, `res` becomes of type `Object` (Not `AsyncResult<Object>`), so we can't call `succeeded` on it.

In this way, it is impossible for you to use a lambda without knowing exactly what type you're inferring with its arguments.

There might be some advanced ways of using a lambda in place of a method whose generic type is declared in its own signature, but I'd need to do some research to illustrate these points. Essentially, even if this could occur, you would need to call `MyClass.<MyType>doSomethingStatic` in order to declare the type before declaring the lambda so that the type can be inferred.

Simply:

You cannot use a lambda where the type cannot be inferred. Generics do not change this.

Comment: correct, OPs misconception is that `Handler<AsyncResult<NetServer>>` is deduced from `res`, but actually `res` is inferred to be `Handler<AsyncResult<NetServer>>` by using the declaration of `listen` method.

Comment: This is very valuable answer, thank you. But how if we would add additional level of generics there: instead of `Handler<AsyncResult<NetServer>>` it would be `Handler <AsyncResult<T>>`? Then I assume, only usage of interface function from `AsyncResult` would be allowed in case lambda would be used?

Comment: @Tomas You're certainly on the right track, although I can't think of an instance where you can enforce a generic type `T` without somehow declaring `T` beforehand. Perhaps a clearer supposition is if you used `AsyncResult<Object>`, wherein if you unwrapped the `Object`, you could only use `Object`'s methods no matter what the actual underlying object type is. I can explain further if that confused you.

Comment: @Zircon if you could elaborate (probably by editing your main answer and maybe pointing out my example with `<T>` generic parameter, that would wrap whole discussion up. Many thanks!

Comment: @Zircon it's not the JVM that infers the types, but the compiler

Comment: @Tomas I have edited my answer. (Also, thanks Eugene.)

Comment: Correction: the *raw type* `MyClass` is *not* treated like `MyClass<Object>`. Raw types do not use Generics at all. Instead, the inferred type of the interface will be the *raw type* `Handler` and `res` will not be `AsyncResult<Object>`, but just `Object`. That’s why you should never use *raw types*. If you use `MyClass<?>`, which denotes an unknown type argument, Generics will work and `res` will be `AsyncResult<?>`.

Comment: I think  just to keep consistency, in edited section `listen` methods shall be replaced with `doSomething` ;)

Comment: Re "The compiler infers the type in the same exact way you do." - I doubt that many folks here apply the exact same strategy in their heads as JLS chapter 18 defines :)